# What is the maximum and minimum values that QSpinBox supports in PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, max, pyside6, pyqt6, qspinbox

What is the **maximum** and **minimum** values that `QSpinBox` supports?

For `QDoubleSpinBox` we can use `float("inf")` to set the `maximum` value and `float("-inf")` to set the **minimum** value.

```
box = QDoubleSpinBox()
box.setMinimum(float("-inf"))
box.setMaximum(float("inf"))
```

But For **QSpinBox** when I do

```
import sys
...
quantity = QSpinBox()
quantity.setMaximum(sys.maxsize)
...
```

It throws error :

```
 RuntimeWarning: libshiboken: Overflow: Value 9223372036854775807 exceeds limits of type  [signed] "i" (4bytes).
  quantity.setMaximum(sys.maxsize)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../createWindow.py", line 180, in addButtonClicked
    quantity.setMaximum(sys.maxsize)
OverflowError
```

I understand that the value which is provided(`sys.maxsize`) is way to big and results in Overflow.

What is the **maximum value** and **minimum value** that I can provide to a `QSpinBox`?

Comment: QSpinBox only accepts 32bit *signed* integers, so within `-2**31` (-2147483648) and `2**31-1` (-2147483647): signed integers have ranges within *half* of their bit size 2-exponent below 0 and above it (minus 1): from `-half` to `half-1`. The documentation of [`sys.maxsize()`](//docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) reports that it returns `2**platform_bits-1`, which on 64bit system is`2**63-1 = 9223372036854775807`, way outside the accepted range. Use [QDoubleSpinBox](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) and [`setDecimals(0)`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop).

Comment: Thanks @musicamante now I have to use `2**31 - 1` as the **maximum value** and `-2**31` as the **minimum value**

Comment: (Typo: it is `2**(platform_bits-1)-1`; sorry about that).